# Flutter Firebase Dynamic Link not working on new ios app install

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-dynamic-links

I am trying to handle dynamic links within my flutter app and they work perfectly when the app is already installed.  The link works fine regardless if the app is open or closed in the background.  However when I try to use a link when the app is not installed I am properly brought to the app store, but then once I open the app from within the app store after the install completes it just opens the app and my dynamic link functionality never executes.

My dynamic link is similar to this:
https://startingxi.page.link/?link=https://url-redacted/game/gameId&apn=myapn&isi=mysi&ibi=myibi&st=new%20team%20vs%20&sd=1%20-%202&efr=1
I have tried with both `efr=1` and without that.

My flutter code:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initDynamicLinks();

    futureInitState = initStateAsync();
  }

  Future<void> initDynamicLinks() async {
    final PendingDynamicLinkData data = await FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.getInitialLink();
    final Uri deepLink = data?.link;
    await processDeepLink(deepLink);

    FirebaseDynamicLinks.instance.onLink(onSuccess: (PendingDynamicLinkData dynamicLink) async {
      final Uri deepLink = dynamicLink?.link;
      await processDeepLink(deepLink);
    }, onError: (OnLinkErrorException e) async {
      print('onLinkError');
      print(e.message);
      displayFlushBar('$e.message');
    });
  }
```

I have tried putting the `initDynamicLinks` within my `futureInitState` which is part of my `FutureBuilder` which does other async stuff at startup.  Any help would be appreciated.  I'm not sure how to debug this problem and this is my first ios/app dev experience so I'm not sure if there are some logs on the ios device that may help?  But at the moment it seems as though I need to deploy to production and get my change live in the app store before I can test anything and that seems less than ideal.  But since the dynamic link works in the other use cases I'm stumped on troubleshooting.

Thanks!

Comment: https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/issues/1861

Comment: have you found a solution for this issue?

Comment: did you found solution?

Answer (score 1):

Common troubleshooting steps for issues on opening Firebase Dynamic Links after app install is to make sure that value of the `ibi` parameter matches the app's Bundle ID.

For Google-provided `*.page.link` domains: in the Capabilities tab of the app's Xcode project, `Associated Domains` shoudld be enabled, and the following is added in the Associated Domains list: `applinks:{your_dynamic_links_domain}`.

Also, verify that the AASA of your FDL `https://{your_dynamic_links_domain}/apple-app-site-association` contains an entry for your app. Verify `"appID":"{team-id}.{bundle-id}"` values are correct for your app

If these steps didn't work, it's best to reach out to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support) as they have the tools to diagnose deeper into this issue.

Comment: it's still not work